# Fill second dropdown with the same value as the first dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a dynamic number of dropdowns. When a value is selected in the first dropdown, the value of the *second and so on dropdowns* will be the same with the first dropdown. But the user has the option to change the value of the *second and so on dropdowns*, but not changing the first and other dropdown's value.

```
<select name="dropdown[]">
  <option value="1">Sony</option>
  <option value="2">Nintendo</option>
  <option value="3">Microsoft</option>
</select>

<select name="dropdown[]">
  <option value="1">Sony</option>
  <option value="2">Nintendo</option>
  <option value="3">Microsoft</option>
</select>

<select name="dropdown[]">
  <option value="1">Sony</option>
  <option value="2">Nintendo</option>
  <option value="3">Microsoft</option>
</select>
```

How can I achieve this using ***javascript*** or ***jquery*** libraries?

Comment: What do you have so far and where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: @jeroen - Actually, I don't have any idea yet. But I do had before a second dropdown populated based from the first dropdown. But right now, I wanted it to be the same value as the first dropdown. A help is gladly appreciated.

Comment: why the use of cascading dropdowns? you can just use the `multiple` attribute. serves the same intention of selection of multiple values

Comment: You have no idea at all? Not even that it should be in a `.change()` handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach a listener to the first select element:

```
var selects = document.querySelectorAll('select[name="dropdown[]"]');

selects[0].addEventListener('change', function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
    selects[i].value = selects[0].value;
  }
});
```

When the value of only the first select changes, it updates the values of the other selects. This way does not rely on any 3rd-party libraries.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cuefb9ag/

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! But the value of the first dropdown isn't showing or submitting. Any good reason why or how to fix it?

Comment: @LoganWayne What do you mean, in the demo it works fine, right? Can you provide additional context?

Comment: When I submit the data, the first array's value is 0.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `change` event and then alter the other dropdowns:

```
$("select[name=dropdown\\[\\]]").change(function() {
    var value = this.value;    
    $("select[name=dropdown\\[\\]]").not(this).val(value);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/awv14f6r/1/

If you want to change them in order (first alters the second, etc) - use `next` along with `this`

```
$(this).next("select").val(value);
```

Comment: Thanks! This is actually great. But the second and so on dropdowns can be changed by the user, not altering the other dropdown.

Comment: @LoganWayne -- Yeah - I edited my answer to include how to only change them in order - or a start of that.

Answer (score 0):

```
var id = $('#DropDownID1 option:selected').val();
 var textValue = $('#DropDownID1 option:selected').text();
        $('#DropDownID2').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
        $('#DropDownID2').select2('data', {
            val: id,
            text: textValue
        });
        $('#DropDownID2 option:selected').val(id);
    }
```